# What set ebooks or evergreen online resources is sufficent for self-study of the topics in an undergraduate math program?

Tags: self-learning, online-resources

What set ebooks or evergreen online resources is sufficent for self-study of the topics in an undergraduate math program?

There are many lists on stack exchange, but they invariably include physical books I can't get shipped to this region.

MIT OCW is fantastic, but it also works with the assumption that learners are in the US and can buy the physical text books the previous MIT classes used.

Edx and Coursera are also fine resources but much of their content is time-boxed and subject coverage is very poor past the freshman/sophomore level.

What ebooks or other set of resources will take a self-paced online learner through a full BA curriculum?

Comment: to get a standard general math education Id say you should learn the calc sequence, combinatorics/probability/graph theory (these may be taught separately or in general discrete math courses), ODEs, PDEs, linear algebra, abstract algebra, and real analysis. I assume you know calculus or can find resources for that. Oscar levin: Discrete math is fully available online and should cover a decent amount of discrete math ideas. Thomas Judson: Abstract algebra is a good intro to the subject also fully available online and contains some cool applications to coding theory/cryptography

Comment: For ODEs and PDEs I’m not too sure but there are so many lecture notes online that it should be easy to choose any and get a decent background

Comment: Ahh okay. Well the two books I suggested have very nice online interfaces and both have plenty of exercises and Solutions. I imagine there are more out there for other subjects but those are the only two I’ve actually looked at

Comment: Thank you, Corey. I was a math major  long ago and am familiar with the courses usually taught. I am struggling to find a chorent set of resources that are all available as ebooks and include exercises. My goal is to provide a learning trail for motivated learners that leads to a successful subject GRE, which is both a stronger signal and more educational than a MOOC certificate.

Comment: Is it appropriate in this sub to update my question with resources as people suggest them to make it easier for others to fill in the gaps?

Comment: For linear algebra, try our "Linear Algebra: Foundations to Frontiers": https://www.coursetalk.com/providers/edx/courses/linear-algebra-foundations-to-frontiers-2#recent